# Reiserfs partition data recovery (success)

Tags: linux, opensuse, data-recovery

i am having windows xp as my os. but i have raiserfs partions created by suse linux on same HDD. i need to recover data from the linux partitions now.

i created opensuse live usb and booted from it. but it is showing free space in disk manager instead of linux partitions. but i accessed from one windows application(e.g Ext2Read ) which is showing linux partitions but not able to recover data from them as they are demo applications.

why opensuse live usb os showing free space instead of linux partitions.

Any other method to recover data from them?

**Update :**
It is showing linux partitions with the tool TestDisk. but it has "write" command only for that. is it safe to do that as i am having windows 7 and suse linux dual boot previously before winxp overrides it. is winxp overwritten and HD instance of previously dual boot recovered from it?

**Good News :**
I successfully recovered by making "write" partition table and now i can access reiserfs partition data from ubuntu live usb bootable. but one of my fat32 drive is missing now. but i will do first recover my data from linux partition first. then check for the fat32 drive.

Comment: Use http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk which is free, opensource and supports many FS including ReiserFS.

Comment: @Shadok Thanks for the link. that tool showing reiserfs partitions now. but is it safe to write that partition structure?

Comment: Testdisk only modifies your partition table, data won't be touched so yes, you can do it safely. If the result is not what you want you can always try another similar tool and recover your files.